# Why it is not possible to create a generic fill method in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following classes:

```
abstract class DTO{ }

class SubscriptionDTO extends DTO { }
```

and the following generic method:

```
protected void fillList(ResultSet rs, ArrayList<? extends DTO> l)
        throws BusinessLayerException {
    SubscriptionDTO bs;
    try {
        while (rs.next()){
            //initialize bs object...
            l.add(bs); //compiler error here
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I can't seem to understand why you can't create a generic method for filling DTO subtypes.  Am I doing something wrong or is this by design?  If so, is there any workaround?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: To answer, I would need to see how you initialize bs, at least the type declaration.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to write the generic method as you planned, since you'll need to know the exact type of bs object in order to create it. For example, new SubscriptionDTO(), or new DeliveryDTO().

Comment: @javashlook -You are right.  mmyers explanation is good enaough for me to realize that.  It seem I will continue using a raw solution for this type of problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using `<? super DTO>` (or `<? super SubscriptionDTO>`, as [Tom Hawtin - tackline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4725/tom-hawtin-tackline) points out) as the generic parameter of the `ArrayList`.

From item 28 of [*Effective Java*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) (page 28 of the [sample chapter](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/generics.pdf) [pdf]):

> Here is a mnemonic to help you remember which wildcard type to use:
>
> **PECS stands for producer-extends, consumer-super.**
>
> In other words, if a parameterized type represents a `T` producer, use `<? extends T>`;
>   if it represents a `T` consumer, use `<? super T>`.

In this case, `l` is a consumer (you are passing objects to it), so the `<? super T>` type is appropriate.

Comment: Or <? super SubscriptionDTO>.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the following situation, with `Foo extends Bar` and `Zoo extends Bar`

```
List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
fooList.addAll(aBunchOfFoos());
aMethodForBarLists(fooList);
```

then we have the method itself:

```
void aMethodForBarLists (List<? extends Bar> barList) {
   barList.add(new Zoo());
}
```

What happens here, is that, even though Zoo does extend Bar, you're trying to add a Zoo in a `List<Foo>`, which is explicitly made for, and only for, Foos.

*This* is why the Java spec disallows adding stuff into a `<? extends Something>` Collection - it can't be sure that, while the syntax *seems* right, the actual objects would allow adding stuff into the Collection.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, and is more straightforward:

```
protected void fillList( ResultSet rs, List<DTO> l ) throws BusinessLayerException 
{
   SubscriptionDTO bs;
   try 
   {
      while   ( rs.next() )
      {
         //initialize bs object...
         l.add( bs );
      }
    }
    catch ( SQLException e ) 
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}